# knitr produces ## with the table code instead of a table in latex document

Tags: r, latex, knitr, rstudio, xtable

When creating a LaTeX document with Knitr in RStudio, the output comes with ## in the PDF result like:

```
 ## % latex table generated in R 3.0.2 by xtable 1.7-1 package
 ## % Thu Feb 20 21:49:34 2014
 ## \begin{table}[ht]
```

I tried some options like:

```
 <<results='asis'>>=
```

But the compiler fails to create the PDF.

Any clues?

My SessionInfo is:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                      
[5] LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xtable_1.7-1    lattice_0.20-24

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] evaluate_0.5.1 formatR_0.10   grid_3.0.2     knitr_1.5.22   stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.2
```

The code chunk:

```
<<>>=

library(xtable)  

Frequencia <- c(3,2,3,4,5,11,14,14,4)  
Soma <- sum(Frequencia)  

dist.freq <- data.frame(
  Intervalo <-   c("10-19","20-29","30-39","40-49","50-59","60-69","70-79","80-89","90-99"),
  Ponto.Medio <- c(14.5,    24.5,   34.5,   44.5,   54.5,   64.5,   74.5,   84.5,   94.5),
  Frequencia,
  Frequencia.Relativa <- Frequencia / Soma  
  )

x <- xtable(dist.freq)

print(x)
@
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. That will provide clues.

Comment: I added the code chunk.

Comment: you should use `=` not `<-` inside your data.frame. Works fine for me besides that. What errors do you get (LaTeX?)

Comment: I changed from <- to = and it fails to compile on RStudio.
The output continues to include the ## before the table code... :(

Comment: @baptiste The output continues to include the ## before the table code... :(

Comment: Your example code chunk does not have results = 'asis'.....

Comment: I did what @baptiste said and search for the problem in the .tex created. Something with the abntex2 package made the output wrong. I removed the class and returned to the default article. The problem don´t exist now. Thanks for the effort. I will try to solve the problem with the abntex2 package now.

Comment: I have the same problem and I could get past ## part of it by including comment = NA inside << >>. But I can't apply results = 'asis' as it somehow corrupts pdflatex process. Thus, I get latex code printed instead of the actual table. I don't use abntex2 at least explicitly. Has anyone advanced in this?

Answer (score 0):

````
```{r TableName, results='asis', echo = FALSE, message = FALSE} 

library(xtable)
Frequencia <- c(3,2,3,4,5,11,14,14,4)  
Soma <- sum(Frequencia)  

dist.freq <- data.frame(
  Intervalo <-   c("10-19","20-29","30-39","40-49","50-59","60-    69","70-79","80-89","90-99"),
  Ponto.Medio <- c(14.5,    24.5,   34.5,   44.5,   54.5,   64.5,       74.5,   84.5,   94.5),
  Frequencia,
  Frequencia.Relativa <- Frequencia / Soma  
  )

print(xtable(dist.freq,caption = "Your caption"), comment=FALSE)
```
````